# Will someone tell me if this answer (mine) is too "cheeky"?

Tags: discussion, answer-quality

Recently I [answered](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/84189/29146) a question that I came across while browsing the unanswered list. Basically I said that the tool that the user was using was now deprecated (even though it wasn't when he asked the question).

I think the answer is useful, because it a. may be useful information for people coming from Google and b. gets the question off the unanswered list, but in the spirit of self-moderation I'd like to ask the community if my answer was too "cheeky". Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is fine. The date on your answer matches with the advice you provided, that for me is more important than giving an outdated answer to an old question about a rolling release distro...

Comment: One additional thing I would like to see in that answer, is how much those two programs are compatible with each other.